# "this" refers to "window" object not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I experimented a bit with **this** keyword and I found a strange problem. When a variable is declared as **var** then **this** correctly refer to this variable. But if i declared the same variable as **let** or **const** then **this** lost reference and show undefined in console.

```js
var prop = "outer"; // not working if let or const.

let foo = {
  prop: "inner",
  show() {
    console.log(this.prop)
  }
}

let a = foo.show;
let b = foo.show.bind(foo);
a()
b()
```

Comment: @adiga I don't believe the duplicate you've marked is a good fit for this question. It does explain what is going on with the `a` call in this snippet - but the question seems to accept that, the question is more about why this doesn't happen when `let` or `const` is used, which as far as I can see isn't addressed at all in the linked question. (Although I haven't read all the comments.)

Comment: "*`this` correctly refer to this variable.*" - no, that's never the correct behaviour. Sure, `this` may refer to the global object in sloppy mode when you don't call the method on  context, but you should never *use* that "feature". In strict mode, `this` is properly `undefined`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Fixed with a proper duplicate target :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this code outside of strict mode (as here), then the `this` keyword defaults to the global object - which in the browser is `window`. (In strict mode it would be `undefined` so `a()` will throw an error.)

The difference in behaviour between `var` and `let`/`const` is a simple consequence of the fact that `var`-declared global variables are the same thing as properties on the global (`window`) object, whereas that doesn't happen with variables (even global ones) declared with `let` or `const`.

See for example [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

> Just like const the let does not create properties of the window object when declared globally (in the top-most scope).